# Вывести сумму SQLite в TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста:
В курсор закидываю Select, а как из него записать значение суммы в txtCounter?

```
userCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM product",null);
txtCounter.setText("Сумма элементов : "+.....);
```

Пока сделала через while, работает но... разве это не костылек?

```
    while (userCursor.moveToNext()) {
                d = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PRICE));
                int point=Integer.parseInt(d);
                mCounter=mCounter+point;
}
txtCounter.setText("Cумма элементов: " + mCounter);
```

Буду очень благодарна за ответ, перешерстила яндекс, но он многозначительно глух к моим запросам(

Comment: но в вашем запросе вы же в курсор и получаете сумму элементов столбца price, вы не знаете как из курсора получить значение для вывода в textview?

Comment: дааа))) бывает и такое)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выборке суммы курсор будет содержать одну колонку с одной строкой, в которой значение суммы, поэтому мы просто читаем из курсора первую строку первой колонки (первая колонка имеет индекс 0):

```
userCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM product",null);
userCursor.moveToFirst(); 
int counter = userCursor.getInt(0);
txtCounter.setText("Cумма элементов: " + counter);
```

Так же колонке с суммой можно присвоить имя, в случае если это единственная колонка в выборке это лишнее, но если колонок несколько, проще обращаться к ней по имени, чтобы не запутаться (назовем колонку *sum*). Тогда изменятся следующие строки:

```
userCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price) AS sum FROM product",null);
...
int counter = userCursor.getInt(userCursor.getColumnIndex("sum"));
...
```

PS: нет надобности получать строку и приводить ее к числу, метод `getInt()` класса `Cursor` сам выполнит это преобразование

Comment: у меня ругается в строке на 0: `int counter = userCursor.getInt(userCursor.getColumnIndex(0));`

Comment: @ЕвгенияБалабанова да, все верно. Мы же не по имени обращаемся к колонке, а по индексу. исправил

Comment: КАК ВСЕГДА - СПАСИБО ВАМ ОГРОМНОЕ!